# How to add innerHTML to div if another div is empty only using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have a issue about javascript. I want to add innerHTML to  div if it is empty. This is my code, please help me review. All div are the same class, not use id and only using javascript. Thanks
html:

```
<div class="B">Test</div> <br/>
<div class="B"></div> <br/>
```

javascript:

```
function test(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("B");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        if (x[i].length() < 0){ 
            x[i].innerHTML = "add test";    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say all `divs` are same class but you have given different class names in html??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: This is my mistake, sorry. They are same class B.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `x[i].innerHTML.length` instead of `x[i].length()` and it wont be *less then zero* at minimum it would be zero.

Few of corrections which I made in your code

- Took length of innerHTML instead of html element div
- Length is a Property so parenthesis should not be used
- Length wont be less than zero so condition should check if length is zero.
- For being on safe side trim the innerHTML before you take length.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b36gmLg7/1/)**

```
function test(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("B");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        if (x[i].innerHTML.trim().length == 0){ 
            x[i].innerHTML = "add test";    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `if(x[i].innerHTML.length==0)`

Comment: You should `trim` the innerHtml to check if it is having actual values.

Answer (score 1):

A jquery solution:

```
$('.B').each(function() {
   var that = $(this);
   if (that.text().length == 0) {
      that.html('add test');
   }
});
```

---

**DEMO**

The last two divs with class B that do not have any text will get filled with string `add test`

```js
$('.B').each(function() {
   var that = $(this);
   if (that.text().length == 0) {
      that.html('add test');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">testA</div>
<div class="B">testB</div>
<div class="B"></div>
<div class="B"></div>
```

Comment: Offtopic question: is there a reason why you use `var that = $(this)`? Why not `if( $(this).text() ....` and `$(this).html(...` ?? @kapantzak

Comment: I want to use $(this) twice, so in order not to call $(this) twice, I store it in var that and call that var, as many times I want

Comment: I think OP wants code for native `javascript` only not using any library like `jquery`.

Comment: Just proposing a jQuery solution. Also, there is a jQuery tag in the question

Comment: The question has a JQuery tag so a JQuery solution is valid in this instance.